# C++ member function applied to object

Tags: c++, methods, functional-programming, member

I want to call member function by passing it as template parameter, without using boost is possible. Here is an example off what I tried to do,

```
class object { void method(); }

{
object object_instance;
...
apply<object:: method>();
...

template<class F>
void apply() { F(object_instance); } // want to call object_instance.F()
}
```

that does not work, so question is how do I go about binding object method to an object.
Thanks

above is an example, not the real code. I have a bunch of functions differing only in name, but with many parameters, that I want to wrap around in operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar(void) {}
};

template <typename R, typename C>
R apply(C& pObject, R (C::*pFunc)())
{
    return (pObject.*pFunc)();
}

int main(void)
{
    foo f;
    apply(f, &foo::bar);
}
```

this.

Comment: thanks, I was trying to do that. I have read about .* operator but this is the first time actually using it

Comment: No problem. You'll have to generate or manually write different variations to allow parameter passing. Boost.Preprocessor would help here. (Though if you're using boost you'd just use `boost::bind`. You're not using boost :P)

Comment: actually arguments are the same, applied inside  apply function, so it works well for me.should have probably provided real code. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your code, and will allow passing a member function as a template parameter:

```
class object { public: void method() {} };
object object_instance;

template<void (object::*F)()>
void apply() {
    (object_instance.*F)();
}

int main() {
    apply<&object::method>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have the problem that the method is always called on the same instance of object?

Comment: Yes, but that's what the original code seemed to do, so I kept it the same. The instance can be passed as a parameter to apply instead.

Answer (score 0):

As a member function isn't a type or integral value, you can't pass it as a template parameter. You could do what you seem to want by creating a struct which calls the member function, though having object_instance in scope in the template is rather smelly.

What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This example is for rvalue references in c++ox. Does not work on all compilers.

```
class Sample
{
public:
    void fun() { cout << "Sample::fun\n"; }
};

template<typename Function>
void FunCall( Function&& f)
{
    f();
}

void RvaluesDemo()
{
    FunCall([&]
    {
        Sample().fun();
    });
}
```

Comment: I didn't so I'm just guessing, but probably because the question isn't tagged C++0x.

Comment: @GMan: No problem.But this would be much more flexible than writing different variations to allow parameter passing.

Comment: Well sure, but this question simply isn't about C++0x.